Read timeout error on recon-ng
I tried to load recon-ng on my Kali Linux but I get the "unable to synchronize module (read timeout)" error message. How can I solve this?
Ps: I have tried reinstalling recon-ng, disable firewall and sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list and it's not working.

"I tried to sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list"  .... is meant to add/remove a repository. What exactly did you intend by doing this?

It was intended to update the content on the source.list repo with deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
